# Permutations of $1,2,....,100$ and counting the cases of a special condition.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider all permutations of the integers $1,2,...,100$. I how many of these permutations will the $25th$ number be the minimum of the first $25$ numbers and the $50th$ number be the minimum of the first $50$ numbers?

I am very weak in these counting problems and combinatorics in general. Any help will be appreciated as I have no idea of where to even begin solving this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Setup:**

- Pick what the first 50 numbers are but don't arrange them yet.
- The fiftieth number must be the smallest of those chosen.
- From those 49 numbers that were chosen which remain, pick which 25 of them appear in the first 25 spaces.
- The 25th number must be the smallest of those chosen in the previous step.
- Arrange the rest of the 24 selected numbers for the first section.
- Arrange the remaining 24 numbers for the second section.
- Arrange the final 50 numbers in the latter half.

Apply multiplication principle and conclude.

Answer (score 2):

If you choose a random permutation $\pi$, then the smallest element of $\pi_1,\pi_2,\dots,\pi_{25}$ is equally likely to be any of the $\pi_i$ for $1\le i\le 25$, so the probability that $\pi_{25}$ is smallest is $\frac1{25}$. Similarly, $\pi_{50}$ has a $\frac1{50}$ chance of being the smallest of the first $50$ elements. Finally, these two events are independent of each other; this is because a random permutation can be chosen by choosing independently, for each element, how it should rank with respect to the previously chosen elements.

Therefore, the probability of a random permutations satisfying your conditions is $\frac1{25}\cdot \frac1{50}$, so the number of permtuations is $\frac{100!}{25\cdot 50}$.